# It is possible to set up DRBD on lxc container?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, lxc

The purpose is I want to set up DRBD to run on lxc container but it looks like different from the physical server because drbd requires to syn from a block device but it does not have in lxc container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRBD is a Kernel driver, and since containers do not have their own Kernel, containers cannot run DRBD. Instead, you would need to install DRBD on the container's host, and replicate the volume/directory on the host that the container is using for storage.

Comment: so mean that is no way to load kernel module in their own lxc container?

Comment: You can use a privileged container to load a kernel module into the host's kernel, but the container doesn't have it's own kernel. LINBIT, the company that created DRBD, does this with their containerized deployments for Kubernetes integration.